# MongoDB/mongoose creating a relation between two models?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am looking to create a one-to-many relationship following this pattern http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

I have an `Exercise.js` schema, which will contain a collection of exercises.

```
var exerciseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  _id: String,
  title: String,
  description: String,
  video: String,
  sets: Number,
  reps: String, 
  rest: Number

});
```

Then I have a workout plan `BeginnerWorkout.js` schema

```
var workoutDaySchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  _id: String,
  day: Number,
  type: String,
  exercises: Array

});
```

I want to associate an array of exercises to the `workoutDaySchema`, this contains a collection of workout days for a particular workout, each day has a collection of exercises.

I have a seeder function that generates the workout for me.

```
check: function() {

    // builds exercises
    Exercise.find({}, function(err, exercises) {
        if(exercises.length === 0) {
            console.log('there are no beginner exercises, seeding...');
            var newExercise = new Exercise({
                _id: 'dumbbell_bench_press',
                title: 'Dumbbell Bench Press',
                description: 'null',
                video: 'null',
                sets: 3, // needs to be a part of the workout day!!
                reps: '12,10,8', 
                rest: 1
            });
            newExercise.save(function(err, exercises) {
                console.log('successfully inserted new workout exercises: ' + exercises._id);
            });
        } else {
            console.log('found ' + exercises.length + ' existing beginner workout exercises!');
        }
    });


    // builds a beginner workout plan
    BeginnerWorkout.find({}, function(err, days) {
        if(days.length === 0) {
            console.log('there are no beginner workous, seeding...');
            var newDay = new BeginnerWorkout({
                day: 1,
                type: 'Full Body',
                exercises: ['dumbbell_bench_press'] // here I want to pass a collection of exercises.
            });
            newDay.save(function(err, day) {
                console.log('successfully inserted new workout day: ' + day._id);
            });
        } else {
            console.log('found ' + days.length + ' existing beginner workout days!');
        }
    });

}
```

So my question is inside building a workout plan, how can I associate the exercises into the `exercises` key using mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
exercises: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Exercise', required: false }]
```

And add an exercise to the workout using the exercise._id (In your code above you'd need to put this in the relevant callback such as the callback for .save on the exercise):

```
newDay.exercises.push(newExercise._id);
```

_id is generally a generated number so I don't know if you can set it to the text string you suggest.

When you .find() a workout you'll need to populate the exercises too. Something like:

```
BeginnerWorkout.find({}).
    .populate('exercises')
    .exec(function(err, exercises) {
    //etc
```

Comment: Cool thanks, so where do I pass the exercise id, ie `dumbbell_bench_press`?

Comment: Actually, this is not totally clear to me. I want to give you a green check, but I need help understanding where the `exercise` actually gets mapped to the Workout?

If a particular exercise has the id `dumbbell_bench_press` I want to associate that exercise with day1 of the workout.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show show you can add references by pushing the _id into the exercises array

Comment: To be clear, I am trying to associate specific workouts.

I may have 3 workouts. `bench`, `squat`, `cleans` and I only want to associate one workout with day one. So lets say day one is `squat` I want to associate that.

Comment: You'll create a new exercise: var squat = new Exercise(...etc)... squat.save().  Then you'll add it to the workout: newDay.exercises.push(squat._id)